# Custom TextView like Facebook

Tags: android

I would like to custom a textview in Android which can handle for see more and less along with hashtag and link clickable like Facebook.
Any solution is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do

change your xml like this.Note that i have added android:maxLines="5".Change whatever show more.. text you want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/texts"
        android:text="some text"
        android:maxLines="5"
       />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/more_text"
        android:text="Show more..."
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in activity do like below code

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.animation.Animation;
    import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        TextView moreTextview;
        TextView texts;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            moreTextview = findViewById(R.id.more_text);
            texts = findViewById(R.id.texts);


            moreTextview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (moreTextview.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Show more...")) {
                        moreTextview.setText("Show less...");

                        texts.setMaxLines(texts.getText().length());
                    } else if (moreTextview.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Show less...")) {
                        moreTextview.setText("Show more...");
                        texts.setMaxLines(5);
                    }

                }
            });


        }
    }
```

Comment: This code is working perfectly, However, is there any solution to add ...See more at the end of the line of text. Really appreciated for your kind answer.

Comment: To do this you have to use relative layout.add See more toRightof texts.

Comment: By doing that, text will not be in the same line. My idea is to concatenate the text and see more together.

Comment: in that case you can try this library https://github.com/mahimrocky/ShowMoreText?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=7555